# How to add an activity in bottom navigation view that already contains fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

I'm using 4 fragments and the MainActivity (which contains the bottom nav) but now because of a particular payment gateway issue with one of the fragments I have changed that fragment into an activity, but as the bottom nav has 3 fragments in it don't know how do add an activity in it, and I also don't want to change all the 3 remaining fragments into activity just to make it work with bottom nav

**Files**

```
MainActivity,Home_Fragment,Caution_Fragment,Donate_Fragment // this is the fragment i changed into activtiy// and About_Fragment
```

is there any way to add an activity in a bottom navigation view that already contains fragments

> if you want to view the Donate_Fragment(Activity) code please tell me
> I will add it

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Deque<Integer> integerDeque = new ArrayDeque<>(3);
    boolean flag = true;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        integerDeque.push(R.id.home_icon);
        loadFragments(new Home_Fragment());
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home_icon);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                item -> {
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    if (integerDeque.contains(id)) {
                        if (id == R.id.home_icon) {
                            integerDeque.size();
                            if (flag) {
                                integerDeque.addFirst(R.id.home_icon);
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                        integerDeque.remove(id);
                    }
                    integerDeque.push(id);
                    loadFragments(getFragment(item.getItemId()));
                    return true;
                }
        );

    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    private Fragment getFragment(int itemId) {
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.home_icon:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
                return new Home_Fragment();
            case R.id.guide_icon:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
                return new Cuation_Fragment();
            case R.id.donate_icon:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
                return new Donate_Fragment();
            case R.id.about_icon:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);
                return new About_Fragment();
        }
        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        return new Home_Fragment();
    }

    public void loadFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        integerDeque.pop();
        if (!integerDeque.isEmpty()) {
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(integerDeque.peek());
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just add an extra case like you did for your home page in navigation item selected callback and start you activity with `startActivity()` there?

Comment: can you explain a little bit more , so i can understand what you're asking

Comment: Currently you load a a fragment into your container when a menu item of your bottom navigation is clicked. You cant load an activity into your fragment container, so I suggested you start a new activity when an menu item of your bottom navigation is clicked. You can do this by checking which menu item is clicked in the `NavigationItemSelectedListener` and run `Context.startActivity`. It is a solution to mix bottom navigation and activity but I wouldn't suggest it, because it results in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: ya actually I'm also trying alternatives, probably removing this from the bottom nav and placing it somewhere else